Is there a complete index of Lean 4 tactics?
I'm wondering if Lean 4 tactics are documented anywhere, in a way comparable to the API documentation for mathlib.
(Sorry for brevity...will edit if this is unclear.)

On the web or from within Lean?  On the web there was a list for Lean 3, and I don’t know why it is taking so long to make one for Lean 4.  From within Lean, you can do #print tactic (you need import Mathlib).

Also it is a bit annoying to cross post questions without letting others know you are doing it: https://leanprover.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/113489-new-members/topic/Lean.204.20tactics.20list It leads to duplicate work.

@Jason Rute, you are right. It occurred to me after posting this that the question was better for Zulip. Should I delete this question?

This question is fine here. Once there's an answer, this is a more permanent place for it.

Maybe https://raw.githubusercontent.com/haruhisa-enomoto/mathlib4-all-tactics/main/all-tactics.md ?

IIRC It is impossible to delete this question after it gets an answer and has a reasonable amount of upvotes. So the site basically discourages you to delete any questions unless they are spam or genuinely bad.

You can use #help tactic (after import Mathlib.Tactic.HelpCmd) to list all tactics available in the current environment. You may also want to import Mathlib.Tactic.Common to make sure mathlib's basic tactics are available, and import Mathlib.Tactic for the kitchen sink.
There is also https://github.com/haruhisa-enomoto/mathlib4-all-tactics/blob/main/all-tactics.md, which is the result of postprocessing the output of #help tactic into markdown form.
This list is automatically generated and just contains the hover documentation for each tactic, so it's not particularly high quality (it includes some semi-internal tactics and tactic combinators, and sometimes the same tactic appears multiple times because it is internally represented as multiple tactics with the same start token and different following syntax, or slight variations on the same tactic). Lean 3 had a specifically curated tactics page but this has not been replicated in lean 4 yet.

Thanks, Mario! I will accept this answer because it indeed answers the title question, as things currently are.

Here is a list that is kept up-to-date and displayed more nicely in a website:
https://seasawher.github.io/mathlib4-tactics/
